# Filtrar con pipe Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando filtrar de la misma manera que lo habré hecho ya unas 20 veces y nose por que pero ahora me tira error y no se de que es, a ver si alguien puede ayudarme

Este es el input en el que busco:

```
 <div class="form-group has-search">
    <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="contactos" name="filterContactos" [(ngModel)]="filterContacto" placeholder="Buscar...">
 </div>
```

Luego saco una lista de contactos que tengo guardada en mi base de datos llamada Contactos:

```
 <div class="contactos" [cdkDragData]="fcontactos" cdkDrag *ngFor="let fcontactos of contactos | filtergroup:filterContacto">
     <div>{{fcontactos.nombre}} - {{fcontactos.dni}}</div>
 </div>
```

Finalmente tengo mi pipe creado llamado filtergroup

```
 if (filterContacto && item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterContacto.toLowerCase()) === -1){
     return false;
 }
```

Finalmente os dejo una captura de mi pipe a ver si veis algo raro..

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { GruposComponent } from '../components/grupos/grupos.component';
    @Pipe({
        name: 'filtergroup'
    })
    export class GruposfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

        constructor(public gruposComp:GruposComponent){

        }
        transform(items:any, filterIdentificador: string, filterPersonal: string, filterPaciente: string, filterContacto:string){
            if (items && items.length){
                return items.filter(item =>{
                    if (filterIdentificador && item.identificador_grupo.toLowerCase() !== filterIdentificador.toLowerCase()){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (filterPersonal && item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterPersonal.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (filterPaciente && item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterPaciente.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                        return false;
                    }   
                    if (filterContacto && item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterContacto.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                        return false;
                    }             
                    return true;
               })
            }
            else{
                return items;
            }
        }

}
```

No me filtra y a parte me tira "item.identificador_grupo is undefined" que no tiene ningún sentido, me está volviendo loco.

Comment: tu filter debe filtrar por todos los campos?

Comment: Hola, @JackNavaRow en princpio solo por el campo nombre, pero no hace nada de nada

Comment: Te *tirar error*... ¿Qué error?

Comment: @PabloLozano no me filtra y a parte me tira "item.identificador_grupo is undefined" que no tiene ningún sentido, me está volviendo loco O.O

Comment: y el arreglo tiene identificador_grupo? intentastes comentar la linea que te da problema?

Comment: @JackNavaRow si, incluso la borre, una vez la borro no me tira el error, pero sigue sin filtrarme

Comment: Está claro que en el array hay un item que no tiene identificador_grupo, lo que hace que `item.identificador_grupo.toLowerCase()` falle.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes arreglar tu GruposfilterPipe , coloco un ejemplo de mas o menos como quedaria(se elimino el constructor y la importacion del componente)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filtergroup'
})
export class GruposfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items:any, strBusqueda : string){
      if(!items) return [];
      if(!strBusqueda) return items;
      strBusqueda = strBusqueda.toLowerCase();
      return items.filter( it => {
       return it.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(strBusqueda)  || it.identificador_grupo.toLowerCase().includes(strBusqueda) ;
    });

    }
}
```

en tu app.module importa el modulo y agregalo a la declaracion:

```
import { GruposfilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';

  declarations: [
...,
    GruposfilterPipe 
  ],
```

y tu HTML quedaria sin modificarse

```
 <div class="contactos" [cdkDragData]="fcontactos" cdkDrag *ngFor="let fcontactos of contactos | filtergroup:filterContacto">
     <div>{{fcontactos.nombre}} - {{fcontactos.dni}}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Entonces mi transform lo reemplazo por ese?

Comment: Nada.. ni se inmuta ni idea de que puede ser, me tiene amargado

Comment: Sí, ya lo tenía agregado de antes, si te fijas el identificador_grupo lo estoy usando en mi componente y ese sin embargo si que me filtra

Comment: que error te arroja?

Comment: Ninguno, no me filtra

Comment: y si quitas la linea `" [cdkDragData]="fcontactos" `?